# Subtract two variable

Tags: jasper-reports

I am designing my reports using Jasper reports, I have an income expense report where I am getting total Income using a variable `TOT_INCOME` and total Expenses using a second variable, `TOT_EXPENSES`. I need to Subtract the two variable to get the Net Profit.
So I have Created a third Variable `TOT_PROFIT`. I am trying to get the Difference this way. On the third Variable Variable Expresion, I have:

```
$V{TOT_INCOME}-$V{TOT_EXPENSE}
```

as My expression. I am getting a wrong output. For example I have this Output:

```
TOTAL_INCOME  TOTAL_EXPENSES   PROFIT
215,762.00    16,012.00        1,587,228.00
```

Which is clearly Wrong as `215,762.00-16,012 = 199,750.00`. All my values are doubles. On the Third Variable, my calculation is `sum`. Please Help where I might be doing a Mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because I want others who might have the same problem to find a solution, I will post what finally worked after tirelessly looking for a solution:

1. Create a new textfield with a class type Double then add the following in your texfield expression:

new Double($V{TOT_EXPENSE}.doubleValue() == 0 ? 0 :
($V{TOT_INCOME}.doubleValue()-$V{TOT_EXPENSE}.doubleValue()))

Done!! This Worked for me.